# Selenium: Find element on drop-down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, indexing, drop-down-menu, element

I'm trying to click on a drop-menu element in selenium but I'm having some  problems. The main problem is that all the elements in the drop-menu don't have id or name, for example the one I'm trying to find has this:

```html
<div>
<span role="menuitem" tabindex="0" style="border: 10px none; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto,sans-serif; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: medium none; font-size: 15px; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; z-index: 1; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); line-height: 32px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; min-height: 32px; white-space: nowrap; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
<div>
<div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px 24px; position: relative;">
<div>CES (Tij)</div>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

I can find the element using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/span/div/div/div"));
```

But for what I understand this option is using indexing, the element "CES (Tij)" is located in the index 2 and if I add a new element  on the drop-down list, the element "CES (Tij)" will not be selected, there's any other way to find the specific element without using the index option?

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='CES (Tij)']"));`

Comment: Thank you Andersson, it worked.